# In Google Apps Script, why do constructors like Array share properties with its prototype?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
 Logger.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array))

  /* 
     [join, reverse, sort, push, pop, shift, unshift, splice, 
      concat, slice, indexOf, lastIndexOf, every, filter, forEach, 
      map, some, reduce, reduceRight, isArray, arguments, prototype, 
      name, arity, length] 
   */


  Logger.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype))

  /* 
     [constructor, toString, toLocaleString, toSource, join, reverse, 
      sort, push, pop, shift, unshift, splice, concat, slice, indexOf, 
      lastIndexOf, every, filter, forEach, map, some, reduce, reduceRight, length]
   */
```

You can see that `Array` and `Array.prototype` have some common properties, like `push`, `pop`, and `reverse`.

Furthermore, you can see that `Array.prototype` has some properties that are inherited from `Object` and then overwritten, like `toString` and `toSource`. If I'm wrong on this, please correct me.

Why would properties like `push` be found both in `Array.prototype` and `Array`? What's the point of doing this? If the goal is to make it so that every array object has access to a `push` method, wouldn't it be enough to have this method defined in `Array.prototype` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called Array generic methods as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods). It was intended to be a shorthand for:

```js
var str = "Hello";
Array.prototype.forEach.call(str, letter=>console.info(letter));
```

Like this:

```js
Array.forEach("Hello", letter=>console.info(letter));
```

It was introduced in JavaScript 1.6 and  therefore present in Google apps script, but they are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! So to be clear, Array.prototype has long-winded method definitions and methods in the Array constructor, which have simpler syntax, invoke the corresponding methods in Array.prototype? And that this way of defining constructor functions is now deprecated?

Comment: @Manuel 1. No. `Array.forEach !== [1,2].forEach`. The former is function  equal to `Array.prototype.forEach.call` receives  two arguments: a this object and a function, while the latter receives a single argument: a function. 2. Yes It's deprecated.  Your logger expressions on other latest js platforms like node js will clearly show the difference.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Methods in `Array.prototype` are called when you run code like `[1,2].forEach`. Methods in the constructor, like `Array.forEach`, are actually different methods that accept a different number of arguments. That explains why the constructor and its prototype have some shared property names. Thanks.